# Как назначить асинхронную обработку горячих клавиш?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, asyncio

Нужно добавить глобальные горячие клавиши. Например, `f4` и `f8`. Использую библиотеку [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard). Есть проблема, пока первый обработчик не закончит работу, новые нажатия клавиш игнорируются.

Другими словами, сейчас работает так

```
pressed f4
end for f4
pressed f8
end for f8
```

А нужно сделать так

```
pressed f4
pressed f8
end for f4
end for f8
```

### Демо код

```py
# pip install keyboard
from keyboard import add_hotkey, wait
from time import sleep

def on_callback(key):
    print('pressed', key)
    sleep(5) # эмуляция долгой работы
    print('end for', key)

add_hotkey("f4", lambda: on_callback("f4"))
add_hotkey("f8", lambda: on_callback("f8"))

wait('esc')
```

Попробовал `asyncio`, но ничего не изменилось

```
pressed f4
end for f4
pressed f8
end for f8
```

```py
from keyboard import add_hotkey, wait
import asyncio

async def on_callback(key):
    print('pressed', key)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('end for', key)

add_hotkey("f4", lambda: asyncio.run(on_callback("f4")))
add_hotkey("f8", lambda: asyncio.run(on_callback("f8")))

wait('esc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разработчик библиотеки [подсказал](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/issues/492#issuecomment-929981014) использовать функцию `keyboard.call_later`. Она создает новый поток для каждого вызова обработчика. Но не выглядит ли это *дорого*? Сделать через `asyncio` так и не вышло.

```py
# pip install keyboard
from keyboard import add_hotkey, wait, call_later
from time import sleep

def on_callback(key):
    print('pressed', key)
    sleep(5)
    print('end for', key)

add_hotkey("f4", lambda: call_later(on_callback, args=("f4",)))
add_hotkey("f8", lambda: call_later(on_callback, args=("f8",)))

wait('esc')
```

На англоязычном SO предложили использовать [пул потоков и очередь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436186/5894542).

Comment: самое забавное что челы вроде тебя создают вопросы, отвечают на них же сами, и выбирают как правильный ответ)))0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через потоки

```
from threading import Thread

def main(key):
    add_hotkey(key, lambda: on_callback(key))

Thread(target=main,args=(“f4”).start()
Thread(target=main,args=(“f8”).start()
```